# UIActivityIndicator is not Animating

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using activity indicator in iphone app but problem is that when I write the line

```
 [indicator startAnimating];
```

in viewDidLoad, it animates but when I write this same line in the button code where I move to next screen then it does not animate

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonClicked{
if ([professionLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Profession"]) {
    errorLabel.text=@"Please Select the Highliteg Answers";
    Q1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
}


if ([workLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Work"]) {        
    errorLabel.text=@"Please Select the Highlight Answers";
    Q2.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
} 



 if([yearLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Year"]){ 
    errorLabel.text=@"Please Select the Highliteg Answers";
    Q3.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
} 




else{
    errorLabel.text=@"";
    Q1.textColor=[UIColor ];
    Q2.textColor=[UIColor];
    Q3.textColor=[UIColor];


   [indicator startAnimating];
    [self submitSurveyAnswers];

    [self submitSurveyAnswersOne];
    [self submitSurveyAnswersTwo];

      OnlineViewController*targetController=[[OnlineViewController alloc]init];
targetController.mynumber=mynumber;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: But When you submitting it you are pushing a new view and Your UIActivityIndicatorView was on your last view and now your current view is on screen . please clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the methods are `NSURLConnection` based. The data sending part might be `synchronous` which pauses the main `UIThread`, which is why the activityIndicator does not animate.

A better way would be to move the data post part to another thread. Replace the following:

```
[indicator startAnimating];
[self submitSurveyAnswers];

[self submitSurveyAnswersOne];
[self submitSurveyAnswersTwo];

OnlineViewController*targetController=[[OnlineViewController alloc]init];
targetController.mynumber=mynumber;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```

with:

```
[indicator startAnimating];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startPosting:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and create two methods:

```
-(void)startPosting{
  [self submitSurveyAnswers];
  [self submitSurveyAnswersOne];
  [self submitSurveyAnswersTwo];
}
```

&

```
-(void)dataSubmissionComplete{
  OnlineViewController*targetController=[[OnlineViewController alloc]init];
  targetController.mynumber=mynumber;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
}
```

and then call the method `dataSubmissionComplete`, when your data has been successfully submitted, on the main thread as:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataSubmissionComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This process is usually followed in such situations where the UI thread animates the activity indicator while data is fetched/posted on another thread in background.

**Edit-** If you want custom activity indicators, take a look at [this](http://www.dejal.com/blog/opensource), [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) and [this](https://github.com/nachiket-webonise/iPhone-Custom-Activity-Indicator) open-source activity indicator files with tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : Download 2 class from [ActivityIndicator](https://github.com/safecase123/ActivityIndicator)

```
Add this class file in your project. Also add QuartzCore framweork in project.

#import "SHKActivityIndicator.h" //in your .pch file of project
```

How use given below: to show indicator use below line.

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivity:) toTarget:self
```

withObject:nil];

```
-(void)startActivity:(id)sender // add this method
{ 
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  [[SHKActivityIndicator currentIndicator] displayActivity:@"Cropping Image"];
  [pool release];
}
```

hide any where u want like this:

```
[[SHKActivityIndicator currentIndicator] hide];
```

---

Add this line of code in button's event by replacing [indicator startAnimating];

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivity:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Add below method which will be called:

```
-(void)startActivity:(id)sender
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   [indicator startAnimating];
   [pool release];
}
```

Comment: This would actually call UIKit from a non main thread, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: it is wokring fine but if i want that this activity Indicator should be like in a windows like UIAlertView then can this be added like that in app

Answer (score 1):

If you add this line to the `-(IBAction)` of a button then it will not show the activity indicator animating because the button action is immediate and the next view will be shown almost immediately. So either you build the `UIButton` programmatically and use the `-(void)` function to  as a selector for the `UIButton` . In that case the `[indicator startAnimating];` would be called then the rest of the button method.

Otherwise you could simply delay the Action in `-(IBAction)`.

Comment: Yes, you should delay the action you are going to do, by use of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or any other means. The problem its you start submittingAnswers right away and you don't give UIKit time to start animating the indicator.